# Select one Dropdown Menu among many - Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, select, onclick

Here is my problem :
I have a list of Universities coming from a MySQL request from a 'university' table. When I click on a 'select' button, an 'onclick' event fills all the subsequent fields describing the address, phone, name etc... of the university. So far, this works fine.

However, I have another MySQL table, 'campus', in which there are other informations, which appear in a dropdown menu. When the user selects a University, the dropdown menu allows the user to select the Campus. This is ruled by the same onclick event which fills the subsequent fields of the University, like this :

```
document.getElementById("Campus_<?php echo $entreprise["ID"]; ?>").style.display = "block";
```

and it is going to display this  menu :

```
<select name="CampusSelect" id="Campus_<?php echo $biZID;?>" class="form-control btn-default btn-sm" style="display: none;">
```

However, if I choose 2 different Universities (like, I run twice the onclick event), the first  menu doesn't disappear, and the  menus start to stack one on top of the other.

What can I do to hide all the other  than the one I want to display ?

Comment: Pelase provide some code

Comment: Sounds like there's something missing in logic to render the `<select>`. Try adjusting what you check for when you render the `<select>`. Maybe you can provide more code.

Comment: Seems like your dropdown menu is being set to display: block to display it but is not being set back to display:none before the next selection. Hard to tell without more code.